# Prolog how to add numbers in a list in a loop?

Tags: prolog

Prolog how to add numbers in a list in a loop?

I have the loop and I would need to add the numbers into a list and render it in the end.

Comment: Can you show your attempt at solving the problem? Note that, in Prolog, you wouldn't use a "loop". You'd do list processing in a recursive predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog is a logical language and not a imperative one. You may need to formulate the problem a bit differently. By formulating what you want and not how you want it.

1. This is a recursive version:

   ```
   the list of numbers between A and B is empty if A >= B or else
   the list of numbers between A ans B is A and the list of numbers between A+1 and B
   ```
2. This is a version with some of prologs features.

   ```
   find all numbers X between A and B
   ```

These two versions can be transferred into prolog quite directly. There is no 'loop' because prolog is not about commands (do this! do that! put that value there! increase!) but about formulating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by *rendering*, but you can create a list of number easily via recursion, since prolog doesn't have loops:

```
range_list(M,M,[M]).
range_list(M,N,[M|R]) :-
  M < N ,
  M1 is M+1 ,
  range_list(M1,N,R)
  .
range_list(M,N,[M|R]) :-
  M > N ,
  M1 is M-1 ,
  range_list(M1,N,R)
  .
```

You could also use built-in predicates to get what you want:

```
range_list(From,To,Result) :-
  findall(X,between(From,To,X),Result)
  .
```